# What is the different --dry-run opportunities?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, dry-run

What is the different between

```
--dry-run
--dry-run=client
--dry-run=server
```

opportunities?

And is there any purpose other than create a definition file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

Passage from the [official Kubernetes `kubectl` references](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands):

> [--dry-run] Must be "none", "server", or "client". If client strategy, only print the object that would be sent, without sending it. If server strategy, submit server-side request without persisting the resource.

The following table should explain it in a much simpler way:

|  | sends data to server/cluster | perform change on server/cluster | validation by the server/cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `--dry-run client` | no | no | no |
| `--dry-run server` | yes | no | yes |
| `--dry-run none` | yes | yes | yes |

Comment: @alidmrc please make sure to accept the answer so that others know it indeed provided the necessary information